# Expected value of an expression

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable such that $\mathbb{E}[X]=1$ and $V a r(X)=2$, then $\mathbb{E}[(X+1)^2]$. Is it true or false?

Solution: $\mathbb{E}[(X+1)^2]=\mathbb{E}[X^2+2X+1]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]+2\mathbb{E}[X] +\mathbb{E}[1]$.

Now, $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=Var(X) + \mathbb{E}[X]^2=2+1=3$.

So $\mathbb{E}[X^2+2X+1]=3+2*1+1=6$.

Hope it's right.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I've another little question: $\mathbb{E}[1]$ is $1$ becaus I have to see it as $\sum_{n=1}1*\mathbb{P}(X=1)$, but $\mathbb{P}(X=1)=1$ ?

Comment: No, this is not correct. The expectancy of a constant, 1 in this case , is always the constant itself. $\mathbb{E}(1)=1$, because you could regard it as a (discrete) random variable $Y$ with constant value 1, this has nothing to do with $X$.

Comment: clear, understood :)

Comment: _What_ is true or false? Is there something missing from the first sentence?

Comment: I'm talking about the equality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is right, and you can consider the another simple variant to do the same:

$$\mathbb{E}[(X+1)^2]=Var(X+1)+{\mathbb{E}[X+1]}^2 = Var(X)+(\mathbb{E}[X]+\mathbb{E}[1])^2 = 2+(1+1)^2=6.
$$